# Selenium Webdriver radio button issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I export Selenium IDE code for automated testing in Selenium Web driver. the code is executed properly but on radio button it stopped and generate error on Selenium Webdriver. Kindly guide me to execute radio buttons successfully on webdriver.

My code is:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ContentPlaceHolder1_ucTriple_rptOffers_AddToCartButton_0")).Click();

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);  
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("rptShoppingServiceGroup_dlAddons_1_ctl03_0_1_0")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("rptShoppingServiceGroup_dlAddons_1_ctl03_1_3_1")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("rptShoppingServiceGroup_dlDevices_1_ctl03_0_1_0")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("rptShoppingServiceGroup_dlAddons_2_ctl01_2")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("rptShoppingServiceGroup_dlDevices_2_ctl03_0_2_0")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("rptShoppingServiceGroup_dlDevices_2_ctl03_0_0_0")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("SubmitButton")).Click();
```

Error found is:

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"rptShoppingServiceGroup_dlAddons_1_ctl03_0_1_0"}
```

how to remove error from it and execute it successfully.

Comment: Is the radio button present inside a frame? In the exported script, are you able to see any commented out frame statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the radio buttons in your page are dynamically generated. Then, there are two possible causes for the error:

- The radio isn't present when you try to click it. Make sure that you have performed the previous steps that make that radio button appear.
- The generated radio button has a different name (the numbers in the name may vary). Try to select it using xpath instead of the exact id.

My suggestion is running the code without the selection instruction, and don't quit the driver (i.e. don't close the browser), so you can inspect the resultant page and look if the radio button is shown and what its actual name is.

Comment: Thanks alot for your suggesstion

Answer (score 0):

The Radio button ID is dynamically generating; we can resolve the issue by creating a **Relative Xpath** with `.contains("text")` that will locate the element, even if the id changes.